# sharepoinonline/Office365 tools to move artifacts form dev site to production site

Tags: sharepoint-online

In SharePointOnline/Office365 are there any tools to move artifacts like masterpages,pagelayouts, wikipages, lists and libraries, webparts etc from Dev site to test site to production site.

Can we use SharePoint designer to move these artifacts across multiple sites?

Also I think we can write custom CSOM managed code to move the artifacts to multiple site collections in office 365. But if I create a C#/visual studio Console application/Windows application can those applications able to connect to Office 365 site based on URL and place the content in respective locations?

Can you share any info\links\pointers on the web that's serves an example of sample console\windows application with CSOM code that does that, for me to get a start?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the Office 365 patterns and practices site provisioning project. It handles provisioning artifacts in to SharePoint Online based off an XML file and I believe it also has export capability to.

https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP/wiki/Monthly-Update-2015-April